# How do I capture a list of all running processes for OSX and save them as a file in Xcode / Cocoa?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I am wanting to capture a list of all running processes for OSX and save them as a file in Xcode / Cocoa.  I googled this and all I found was:

[myWorkspace runningApplications];

And I am not sure how to do this. Please Help! Thank you!

Comment: That method will return you an array of NSRunningApplication objects. How you save them to a file depends on what information you want about each one, and what format you want to save them in.

Comment: Please be more specific: What is your overall goal? What information about the running applications do you want to save? What have you tried so far?

Comment: The overall goal is to create a text or csv file that lists all of the running processes on the computer, and to list the process name and the path of the process.

Comment: You still have to decide what you mean by "process": a Mach task, a BSD process, a Classic/Carbon/Cocoa process/application, what Activity Monitor shows with certain settings, what ps prints out with a certain set of flags (which is close to "BSD process"). For that matter, does "all" mean "on the machine", "for the current user", or "in the current session"? There are different answers for each case—and unfortunately the answers are _very_ different—it's not just a matter of "pass a different value for the third param", it's completely different APIs from different layers of the OS.

Comment: I think the ps -ax method will work great, if I can get it to work.  Is it pretty efficient on the CPU?  Is ps -ax basically "All Users" processes?  Thanks again!

Comment: It's almost exactly the same as all users' and system processes at the BSD level. It's also a well-defined thing that you can explain to users. As for performance, I believe it works by just filtering and formatting the same `sysctl` output used by `GetBSDProcessList`; there's obviously some CPU wasted formatting the data just to parse them, but probably not enough to matter. (You can test and see.) A more important issue is how easy it is to parse. I'd suggest adding more params to `ps` so it only shows exactly what you want. (Read the manpage and experiment.)

Answer (score 13):

As explained in [QA1123](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/#qa/qa2001/qa1123.html), "process" means multiple different things on a Mac (and that changes over time).

A "process" at the level of Cocoa (or Carbon, or once upon a time Classic) is basically what an end-user thinks of as a process: an app, fba, launchitem, etc. A "process" at the level of BSD is what a Unix-trained sysadmin thinks of as a process: something that shows up in `ps`. A high-level process can have multiple BSD processes; the other way around used to be possible too (under Classic); you can also have BSD processes that have no high-level process; etc.

If you want the high-level definition, forget that QA, the method `-[NSWorkspace runningApplications]` that you mentioned returns exactly what you want: an array with an object for each such app, and those objects have all the info you want. How you save them in a file depends on what information you want about each one, what format you want to save that information in, etc. Here's a complete sample app that will save the URL of each app, one per line, to a file called "./appslist":

```
#include <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  NSString *output = [NSString string];
  for (NSRunningApplication *app in 
       [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications]) {
    output = [output stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@\n",
                     [[app bundleURL] absoluteString]];
  }
  [output writeToFile:@"./appslist" 
           atomically:YES
             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                error:NULL];
  return 0;
}
```

If you want the low-level definition, the code in that QA is still accurate. Or you could just `exec` (or `system` or `NSTask`) `ps`.

Anyway, here's a sample that (with the code from that QA) prints the pid of each running process to a local file called "./bsdlist":

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  kinfo_proc *procs;
  size_t count;
  int err = GetBSDProcessList(&procs, &count);
  if (err) return err;
  FILE *f = fopen("./bsdlist", "w");
  for (size_t i=0; i!=count; ++i) {
    fprintf(f, "%d\n", procs[i].kp_proc.p_pid);
  }
  fclose(f);
  free(procs);
}
```

If you like the idea of scripting `ps`, as mentioned above, there are a number of ways to do this.

The `DDTask` library mentioned in Dominik's answer looks like the easiest way to do this. If you want to use `NSTask` directly, it takes a bit more code to set up an `NSPipe` for stdout, etc. There's a good general [CocoaDev](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSTask) (it's scripting `ls` rather than `ps`, but the ideas are all the same.)

Or you could drop down to a lower level. You could explicitly `fork`/`exec` and pass the results through stdout, but the `popen` function is designed to wrap all of that up, and it's a lot easier to use. [The GNU C Programming Tutorial](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Programming-with-pipes.html) shows how to `popen` `ps -A` and pipe it to `grep init`; the first half of this is all you need.

Whichever way you go, the problem is that you're going to get back a mess of strings you have to parse. The best thing to do is pass different flags to `ps` to only get what you actually want. If all you want is the command lines, `ps -ax -ocommand=` will give you nothing but that, one command line per line—no header line to skip, no columns to parse apart, etc.

If you're worried about efficiency: The QA says "exec'ing ps will require parsing the tool's output and will not use system resources as efficiently as Listing 1." And this is true; formatting the `sysctl` output into strings just to pass them over a pipe and parse them again is extra work that has to take *some* CPU time. But unless you're doing this millions of times, I doubt it uses enough to make a difference. The best approach (to this, and most cases) is to write the simpler code first and test whether it's fast enough; if it is, you're done.

Comment: Cool, thank you!  I will play around with these different methods and see what works the best for my app.

Comment: Thank you again for the help, but I am a newbie when it comes to objective C.  I have tried to insert this code into my project in various locations, but cannot seem to make it create the appslist file.  Where is this file created?  And I was curious if it included the path of the process.  Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Well, "./applist" or "./bsdlist" is in the current directory. I did this for simplicity—you can just build those as command-line apps and they'll work—but for a GUI app, "the current directory" is not a well-defined thing. For testing, put in an absolute path; for production, ask the user where to save it.

Comment: I ended up using the [NSWorkspace runningApplications] method, and it will write to the NSLog, but I cannot get it to write to a file.  I tried to add a sub directory to see if it would create a folder, but it wouldn't do that either.  It also did not like the return 0;, is that necessary?  It said void method should not return a value.  Is it not writing to a file because it is in a void method?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: The `return 0` is there because `main` is not a `void` function; if you're putting the same code into a `void` function, then yes, just `return`—or, since this is at the end of the function, just leave it off. As for why it's not writing to a file, that's probably a separate question; either way, please explain exactly what you did and what didn't work.

Comment: Thanks, great answer, especially the link to Apple's lower-level code (which runs 10 times faster than NSTask of 'ps -el' and collecting the Pipe data into NSData object. But if I choose the lower level - how can I then extract the command-line arguments for a procs[i].kp_proc ?

Answer (score 1):

yip to get high-level query the workspace as shown by abarnet
to get 'all' processes go lower-level and execute ps via an NSTask and read the response via a NSPipe.

there's sample code by apple ..
or use DDTask (a wrapper I wrote) [github repository](https://github.com/Daij-Djan/DDUtils/tree/master/model/DDTask%20%5Bosx%5D)

```
NSString *exe = @"/bin/ps";
NSArray *args = @[@"-ax"];
NSString *res = [DDTask runTaskWithToolPath:exe andArguments:args andErrorHandler:nil];

[res writeToFile:@"./appslist" 
      atomically:YES
        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
           error:NULL];
```

Comment: Cool, thank you!  I will play around with these different methods and see what works the best for my app.

Comment: I haven't gotten this far yet, but hopefully I will soon :).  Thank you :).

Comment: +1. This is definitely simpler than trying to use NSTask (or fork/exec with a piped stdout or whatever) on your own for a self-described ObjC newbie. So if the OP decides the results of `ps -ax` are what he wants, this is probably the best way to get it.

Comment: Yes, I played around with ps -ax in the terminal, and I think that will work.  Is there any chance you could give me a couple more clues now that we know what method I am going to use?  I am not sure what do to with the DDTask wrapper.  Do I import it into my project as a class?  Thank you guys for all of your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: It looks like he's designed it so you can pick and choose at almost any level. You can just copy `DDTask.m` and `DDTask.h` into your Xcode project (they don't depend on anything else from his library), or put the whole `DDTask.xcodeproj` as a subproject, or even build the whole `DDUtils` project as a framework. If he doesn't have any recommendations, I'd do the first.

Comment: I'm not sure which sample code he was referring to, but really, it'll be easier to use his `DDTask` than to write it yourself with `NSTask`. If you want to do it at a lower level (e.g., with `popen`), I believe the Unix Programming FAQ and the GNU C Programming Tutorial both have sample code for that (except they probably use `-ef` instead of `-ax` to be SysV compatible).

Comment: I couldn't find an Apple sample, but I added links to my answer for samples of using NSTask and popen. But again, if this is the approach you want, I'd use his DDTask. (But see my answer anyway about the command line you want to send to ps.)

Comment: @abarnert:: I'd go with your first option too. anyways it should a really thin wrapper around NSTask and NSPipe . for these there is apple sample code btw