# How to show all running process on macOS programmatically in C++?

Tags: c++, macos, pid

macOS doesn’t have procfs.

Does anybody know some analogs or anything else that can help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431643/how-do-i-capture-a-list-of-all-running-processes-for-osx-and-save-them-as-a-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I capture a list of all running processes for OSX and save them as a file in Xcode / Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431643/how-do-i-capture-a-list-of-all-running-processes-for-osx-and-save-them-as-a-file)